# Transform Image.memory to File without save the image on phone

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

Is possible to transform an image stored in memory to File so that I can upload it to the Firebase Storage without having to save it on the phone? The Firebase Storage is in File.

This is what I need to transform into File to return a Future  to be able to save it to Storage, but I couldn't.

```
Image.memory(Uint8List.view(pngBytes.buffer));
```

And this is the full code:

```
  setRenderedImage(BuildContext context) async {
    ui.Image renderedImage = await signatureKey.currentState.rendered;

    setState(() {
      image = renderedImage;
    });

    getFileImage(context, image);

  }

Future<Image> getFileImage(BuildContext context, image) async {
  var pngBytes = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);

  return Image.memory(Uint8List.view(pngBytes.buffer));
}
```

I hope you can help me,
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there anything preventing you from using the `putData` method of Firebase Storage?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore doesnt work :(

Comment: @MatíasNicolásNúñezRivas How did you try using `putData`?  You say it "doesn't work", but what happened?

Comment: Did you check **File.fromRawPath()** method? Although it doesn't accept an Image object, but it does accept a Uint8List which might work for you.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore Your answer was the correct. I only needed to transform my rendered image to ByteData and after transform to Uint8List... These way it work with putData(). Thanks you a lot.